# Global variable not being updated with a thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading, variables, global

I have a Thread that is checking every hour of a time and keep updating a global variable, for some reason global statement is not working and it's keeping the same value in the global variable even if the thread update it, please reference to my code:

```
paymentDate = "2024-03-22"
currentDate = ""

#Function that is in charge of validate the date
def isSystemValidDateReached():
    global currentDate

    try:
        if currentDate == "":
            currentDate = str(urlopen('http://just-the-time.appspot.com').read().strip().decode('utf-8'))

        if paymentDate < currentDate:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except Exception as e:
        log.appendToLog("Error", "critical")


#function that is being used in a thread
def getTimeFromInternet(timeSleep=3600):
global currentDate
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(timeSleep)            
        currentDate = str(urlopen('http://just-the-time.appspot.com').read().strip().decode('utf-8'))
        print("new current date {}".format(currentDate)) 
    except Exception as e:
        log.appendToLog("Error: {}".format(e), "critical")
```

This is a portion of how it looks in main script and this function is being checked in a while loop every certain time:

```
if isSystemValidDateReached():
    exit()

# get time every hour
getDateFunctionThread = multiprocessing.Process(target=getTimeFromInternet)
getDateFunctionThread.start()
```

The problem that I'm facing is that I have a breakpoint in `getTimeFromInternet` function and it updates `currentDate`, but when the function `isSystemValidDateReached()` is called, I see the same old value assigned in this portion of code:

```
if currentDate == "":
        currentDate = str(urlopen('http://just-the-time.appspot.com').read().strip().decode('utf-8'))
```

What needs to be changed to have this variable getting updated every hour in my threaded function?

Comment: `multiprocessing` does not create threads, it creates new process, each of which gets its *own* copy of the global variable `currentDate`.

Comment: Thank you! I have changed to Thread instead and it works.

Comment: You aren't using threads anywhere in your code. This is *crucial to understand*. A `multiprocessing.Process` creates a subprocess, not a thread.

Comment: How does getTimeFromInternet() terminate? How does making the HTTP request give you a value that differs from datetime.datetime.now() (apart from the format)?

Answer (score 0):

As chepner state, how was solved is because I was using multiprocessing instead of thread, see the code as follows:

```
getDateFunctionThread = Thread(target=getTimeFromInternet)
getDateFunctionThread.start()
```